# App to add second mouse pointer?

Tags: windows-xp, vnc, screen-capture, screencasts, tightvnc

I am using [kindlevncviewer](https://github.com/hwhw/kindlevncviewer) to display the screen of a Windows XP PC on a Kindle. This VNC viewer, however, seems to be [incapable of displaying a mouse cursor](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showpost.php?p=2428129&postcount=336).

**Is there a small app for Windows XP that can make a (non-rectangular) window follow the mouse cursor position?**

That window should display something like a mouse cursor itself, but as it's a window and not a real cursor, it will be rendered by kindlevncviewer (or any other program that has the same issue, such as simple screen capture programs).

I already tried [Neko 98](http://neko.en.softonic.com), which would be better than nothing, but the cat is not
showing in the VNC client.

Answer (score 0):

I too use this. And would love to get this working.

An application level solution would be handling LibVNCClient's HandleCursorPosProc callback properly within [kindlevncviewer](https://github.com/hwhw/kindlevncviewer) itself.

This is beyond my powers but worth mentioning. This point has been raised on the [MobileRead](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?p=2409085#post2409085)

HTH.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks! Though I think your message would better be a comment to my question.

Comment: Maybe so... I didn't see an add comment link on your question (still don't now) so was careful to craft this as a partial answer at the very least. ;)

Comment: I value your insight. Still, I designed this question to not be specific to kindlevncviewer. It's really just about adding a second cursor.